# Comprobar si dos variables son iguales JS

Tags: javascript

Estoy ante un simple error en js pero que no logro dar con ello por más que miro

Necesito comprobar si los dos input coinciden, y si es así, mostrar un mensaje debajo.

Pero por lo que veo en la consola, no se guarda la información del input en las variables

```js
function passwordCheck(){

  var pass = document.getElementById("inputPassword3");
  var passCheck = document.getElementById("inputPassword4");

  if (pass === passCheck) {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Coinciden!";
  }
  else{
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "no coinciden!";
  }
 }
```

```html
<input type="password" id="inputPassword3" required>
<input type="password" id="inputPassword4" required onkeypress="passwordCheck()">
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: a tus dos variables añadeles al final del `document....` esto = `.value`

Comment: o tambien el propio if pon `pass.value` y `passCheck.value`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El problema como comentaba un compañero es que no ponias `.value`, así que en vez de comparar sus valores, comparabas los elementos, y no eran los mismos.

Además, mejoré un poquito el código con los siguientes puntos:

- Es mejor separar las funcionalidades de los scripts de los tags html, por eso, en vez de usar un `onkeypress`es preferible 'setear' el `event` desde el mismo script.
- Usar `let` en vez de `var` aprovechando al máximo las nuevas funcionalidades del estándar de JS.
- Usar la condición ternaria para reducir la cantidad de líneas de código.
- Sustituir el evento `onkeypress` que realmente ejecuta el `onkeydown` porque si no, va 'retardado' una caracter ya que nunca coge el actual, si no el anterior. El evento `input` indica el cambio del valor del `elemento input`.

```js
document.getElementById("inputPassword4").addEventListener('input', function() {
    let pass = document.getElementById("inputPassword3").value;
    let passCheck = this.value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = pass === passCheck ? "Coinciden!" : "No coinciden!";
});
```

```html
<input type="password" id="inputPassword3" required>
<input type="password" id="inputPassword4" required>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 6):

Tienes que añadir el atributo value al final de la llamada dom del input, porque estas comparando el "htmlElement" de los input y no su valor por lo que siempre va a entrar en el else.

```js
function passwordCheck(){

  var pass = document.getElementById("inputPassword3").value;
  var passCheck = document.getElementById("inputPassword4").value;
    
        
  if (pass === passCheck) {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Coinciden!";
  }
  else{
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "no coinciden!";
  }
 }
```

```html
<input type="password" id="inputPassword3" required>
<input type="password" id="inputPassword4" required onkeyup="passwordCheck()">
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
function passwordCheck(){

  var pass = document.getElementById("inputPassword3").value;
  var passCheck = document.getElementById("inputPassword4").value;
    
        
  if (pass === passCheck) {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Coinciden!";
  }
  else{
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "no coinciden!";
  }
 }
```

```html
<input type="password" id="inputPassword3" required>
<input type="password" id="inputPassword4" required onkeyup="passwordCheck()">
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Tenías dos problemas que hacían que tu código no funcionase:

1: Lo que capturabas en las variables era el **item** del **DOM**, no el valor de este. Añadiéndole `.value` extraes el valor que tenga el `input`.

2: El evento que usabas para llamar a la función, no cumplia bien con la evaluación, ya que con el `onkeypress` no puedes capturar el caracter que se acaba de introducir, por lo que si por ejemplo, validas una contraseña de 4 dígitos la comprobación de igualdad se lanzaría al introducir el quinto. Para solucionarlo basta con usar el evento `onkeyup`.